# Pass data from ajax to laravel 5.1 Controller in order to save to mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I need to pass data from jquery (version 1.9.1) to my Controller (Laravel 5.1) and then save it to mysql.

How to do that and pass the variable slot? It didn't work so far. For any further details, please asked me.

jquery:

```
 $(".tic").click(function(){
    var slot = $(this).attr('id');
    playerTurn(turn, slot);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addhistory',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { _token: {{ csrf_token() }}, moves: slot },
        success: function()
        {
            alert("Data has been saved successfully!");
        }
    });
 });
```

Controller:

```
 public function addhistory(Request $request)
    {
        $history = new History();
        $history->game_id = Game::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
        $history->moves = $request->moves;
        $history->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/addhistory', 'GameController@addhistory');
```

Errors in console:

```
(index):198 Uncaught ReferenceError: HAmcYRScL9puItnUGbd2kHx.... is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):198)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (191.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (191.js:3)
```

---

191.js file is the jquery version of 1.9.1

Comment: did you tried placing single quotes around `{{ csrf_token() }}` ?

Comment: try `_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'`. Because CSRF may contain some arithmetic operators  and JavaScript try to evaluate it.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/addhistory 500 (Internal Server Error) I get this error with this

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace a get exact error?

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/addhistory 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ 191.js:5
ajax @ 191.js:5
(anonymous) @ (index):195
dispatch @ 191.js:3
v.handle @ 191.js:3

Comment: your script is working fine on client side. Please check the error at server side. you can see it in `storage/log/laravel.log`

Comment: Try `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'}, data: {'moves': slot },`
instead of `data: { _token: {{ csrf_token() }}, moves: slot },`

Comment: You are doing a redirect in your controller `return redirect()->back();`, instead you need to send a response back. You may get a 302 Http response in the network tab for the ajax request

Comment: It was an error at server side. I checked the laravel.log and found a solution. The answer was given by Vaibhavraj.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it may works

```
 $(".tick").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    var form = $(this);
    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    var url = form.attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
           alert("Data has been saved successfully.");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
$(".tic").click(function(){
  var slot = $(this).attr('id');
  var token= $("input[name='_token']").val();
  playerTurn(turn, slot);
  $.ajax({
      url: '/addhistory',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { '_token': token, 'moves': slot },
      success: function()
      {
          alert("Data has been saved successfully!");
      }
  });
});
```

And in your controller you don't need return redirect because the request is asynchronous. So I am returning true. Make sure you include History model at the top of your controller

```
 public function addhistory(Request $request)
    {
        $game_id=Game::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
        History::create([
                        'game_id'=>$game_id,
                        'moves'=>$request->moves
        ]);
        return true;
    }
```